# Find matching rows in a csv file using two column matching (Python)

Tags: python, csv, matching

I need to be able to find the matching row in a csv file, where value from one column named destination matches a variable from my python script, and value from another column named line matches another variable from the script, to retrieve another column (named code) value from the file.

How do I do that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Write some bad code, fix the errors, ask if you get stuck. That's what I do.

Comment: I currently have code to match one column only, but not two. That's why I ask.

Comment: Show your code, and what you've tried. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I finally moved feeding my csv file in a sqlite3 database and making requests on it in my script, that seemed simpler to me and faster with huge files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pandas library in python

```
import pandas as pd
filename="filename.csv"
df=pd.read_csv(filename)
variabletomatch="whateveryouwanttomatch"
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    tomatch=row["columnname"]
    if tomatch==variabletomatch:
        print "MATCHED"
```

Comment: Sure, but here we only match one column, and I need to match two different variables to two different columns from the csv...

Comment: That's the solution I temporarily used to solve my problem, but I just moved to feeding my csv file in a sqlite database and making requests on it in my feed. What used to run in 3min using pandas now take less than 10sec using sqlite. Thanks for your help :)